# Disable ssl session resumption on wildfly 10

Tags: ssl, jboss, wildfly

i need to disable ssl session resumption on wilfly 10 community edition. I tried to modify undertow ssl session-cache-size and ssl-session-timeout unsuccessfully. Any suggestions are welcome. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is any options for that, if the `ssl-session-cache-size` is not working.

As an alternative, you could consider off-loading TLS using a reverse proxy with support for ssl session resumption (e.g. [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/)).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Johan, the workaround of use a proxy http server like nginx  it could be ok, but in our environment required some application modification.